# Haskell. Need a function "complimentar" that takes a list whith expanded representation according to the rules

Tags: haskell

Implement a function "complimentar" that takes a list whith expanded content according to the rules  as input and compressed its  representation according to the rules:

```
complimentar [Single 'c',Multiple 'v' 2,Multiple 'c' 2,Single 'f']
--"cvvccf"
```

I began to solve the problem with the implementation of the data type:

```
data CompData = Multiple Char Int | Single Char deriving (Show)
```

How to solve this problem further, I do not understand. Help me find a solution.

Comment: Hint: start with a function that maps a single `CombData` object to a String, then take a look at `concatMap`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. But it seems to me that this is not an optimal solution. Help find a simpler solution, if a simpler solution exists..

1) I implement the required data type.

```
data CompData = Multiple Char Int | Single Char deriving (Show)
```

2) I implement a helper function for converting the CompData type used to the standard type.

```
convert :: CompData -> (String, Int)    
convert (Multiple x y) = ([x], y) 
convert (Single x) = ([x], 1)
```

3) I implement a helper function to multiply a string by a number.

```
umn :: String -> Int -> String
umn s 1 = s
umn s 0 = ""
umn s x = s ++ (umn s (x - 1))
```

4) I implement a helper function to complex an expression of type CompData into a String.

```
umnlist :: CompData -> String
umnlist (Multiple x y) = umn (fst (convert (Multiple x y))) (snd (convert (Multiple x y)))
umnlist (Single x) = umn (fst (convert (Single x))) (snd (convert (Single x)))
```

5) I implement the "complimentar" function.

```
complimentar :: [CompData] -> String
complimentar [] = ""
complimentar (x : []) = umnlist x
complimentar (x : xs) = umnlist x ++ complimentar xs


Input: complimentar [Single 'c',Multiple 'v' 2,Multiple 'c' 2,Multiple 'f' 1]
Output: "cvvccf"
```

Comment: If you want a simpler solution, you can take your working code to Code Review.